# What does it mean when we say the time complexity is O(M+N)?

Tags: algorithm, graph, asymptotic-complexity

Is it the same as saying

```
O(max(M,N))?
```

I am learning time complexity and this type of complexity comes up time and again with graphs.I don't fully understand what they mean by

```
O(M+N),
```

where M=number of edges
      N=number of vertices.

Comment: Instead of asking this question, try proving it's true using the definitions. If you can't do that, try proving that it's false. If all else fails you can post your attempts here or on another forum (computer science stack exchange or math stack exchange perhaps?). But I think if you just look at the definition of Big-Oh you'll find it to be true pretty fast (well, after you gain some basic understanding of the rigorous definition).

Comment: Also, the reason they tend to say `O(M+N)` is because it's a tighter bound and also clearer. It usually means "we  process edges and vertices for linear time" while `O(M)` would give you the impression that perhaps the algorithm ignores vertices entirely. It also helps because graph algorithm implementations often vary significantly in performance. If your graph is sparse (i.e. `|M|` is _very_ small) then you might not care that there's an `O(M^2 * ...)` factor in the time complexity (i.e. you'd prefer `O(M^2 * logN)` vs `O(M*N)` despite the former being asymptotically slower).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is `O(M+N)` the same as `O(max(M,N))`?

Yes, it is the same. Without losing generality, you can say that `M >= N`. Therefore, `O(max(M,N))` is the same as `O(M)`. At the same time, `M < M+N < M+M`, so `O(M+N)` is the same as `O(2*M)`, which is in turn the same as `O(M)`.

Comment: Without losing generality? I'd say you're talking about an upper bound. What if the graph is sparse?

Comment: @TheEmeritus That does not matter: of the two numbers `M` and `N` one will be greater, and the other will be  smaller, or they would be equal. If the one you initially labeled `N` happens to be larger, you can relabel it as `M`.

Comment: @TheEmeritus To follow up on dasblinkenlight's reply, he's referring to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality. It means that the proof is essentially still the same in other cases (often because you can just rename a variable as we see here). I don't actually really like this proof since it doesn't really refer to the definition of Big-Oh and depends on the transitivity of Big-Oh when it doesn't really need to (i.e. it feels roundabout to me). But for casual purposes I think it's clear enough

Comment: What if we had a graph with ten million vertices and no edges?

Comment: @Aravind Then the `max(E,V)` would be `10,000,000`, and the `E+V` would be `10,000,000` as well. The core of my proof is that `E+V` cannot exceed `2*max(E,V)`, therefore `O(E+V) == O(max(E,V))`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `N` vertices, the number of edges may vary (between `0` to `N^2`, if it's a directed graph, and between `0` and `(N^2)/2`, otherwise). This is why when giving an answer, you have also `N` and `M`. Of course, you can say that `O(M+N) = O(max(M,N))`, but the casual way to say it is `O(M+N)`.